# Extjs PUT url with wrong id

Tags: rest, url, extjs, model

I'm new to senach and ExtJs, and I'm trying to read and write `json` data. getting the data is already working, but I can't write changed data back to the server.

I'm using a **ExtJs 4.2**.

I configured one URL in the RestProxy url: `/animals/dogs/`

GET [`http://example.com/animals/dogs`](http://example.com/animals/dogs)

PUT[`http://example.com/animals/dogs/{id}`](http://example.com/animals/dogs/%7Bid%7D)

Get is working as expected. But the PUT URL is:

```
example.com/animals/dogs/project.model.dogs-3?dc435453...
```

The id also contains the model name. How can I change this to the id like above?

This is the store:

```
Ext.define('project.store.MyJsonStore', {


 extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'project.model.dogs',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            autoSync: true,
            model: 'project.model.dogs',
            storeId: 'MyJsonStore',
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                limitParam: 'count',
                url: '/animals/dogs,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    idProperty: 'id',
                    root: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

This is the model:

```
Ext.define('project.model.dogs', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Field'
    ],

    clientIdProperty: 'id',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'type',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ]
});
```

GET Respones:  (reader root is data)

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": 
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "Some Type",     
      "url": "/animals/dogs/1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "Some other Type",     
      "url": "/animals/dogs/2"
    },  

  ]
}
```

The PUT urls look like:

```
example.com/animals/dogs/project.model.dogs-3?dc...
example.com/animals/dogs/project.model.dogs-7?dc...
example.com/animals/dogs/project.model.dogs-8?dc...
```

The numbers 3, 7, 8 are the id's, so extjs recognizes the id property in the model.

Regards,
Sencha Beginner

Comment: What do your model definition and GET response look like? This behavior usually happens when you don't have the idPropety on the model configured correctly

Comment: In other words, it's behaving as designed--but using an auto generated id since you don't have one configured on your model

Comment: I tried to set idProperty to id, but same problem. According the docs "id" should be the default.

Comment: added model, store and GET response

Comment: Have you tried removing clientIdProperty? According to the docs, you're not using it correctly and that's probably creating the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the problem.

Comment: I changed the record like this: **record.data.type = "test"** and the right way to do this is **record.set('type','test');** Now it's working.